# How to use LINQ to check if all dates are coming from same month

Tags: c#, linq

I have one date filed in one object . I want to check if all dates are coming from same month [ Month can be anything ].

Below are the example for checking coming date are from current month .

```
@Model.Events.Where(d => 
   System.Convert.ToDateTime(d.Eventdate).Month == System.Convert.ToInt32(month))
```

Comment: Is month a constant, for example are you checking to see if they are all from July?  Or do you just want to know if they are from the same month with no target month in mind?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Enumerable.All()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it verifies if all items in sequence satisfy condition:

```
@Model.Events.All(d => 
   Convert.ToDateTime(d.Eventdate).Month == Convert.ToInt32(month))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use something like:

```
bool allSameMonth = @Model.Events
                          .Select(x => x.EventDate.Month)
                          .Distinct()
                          .Count() < 2;
```

(I've taken the liberty of assuming you're going to change your `Eventdate` model property from a `string` property to a `DateTime` property, and capitalize the `D`. You *really* don't want to use strings all over the place. Convert to `DateTime` as early as you can, and then convert back to strings only where you need to.)

This code doesn't care which month it is - only that there are fewer than 2 distinct months. (This means that "there are no events" counts as well. You need to consider how you want to handle that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Model.Events.Where(d => 
   d.Eventdate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
```